# Is this a convolution of two PDFs?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

This is my first question on the site!
I want to get the sum of two (or more) random variables, so I did this

```
from scipy.stats import exponweib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
shape, scale, delta = 1.3, 12, 1e-2

dist = exponweib(a=1, loc=0, c=shape, scale=scale)
grid = np.arange(0, 100, delta)
pmfs = dist.pdf(grid)*delta

# Do convolution (?)
def conv(a,b):
    x = np.array([sum(a[:i+1]*b[i::-1]) for i in range(len(a))])
    return x

# Loop to convolve over multiple RVs
c = {1: pmfs}
for i in range(2, 4):
    c[i] = conv(c[i-1], pmfs)

plt.plot(grid, c[1])
plt.plot(grid, c[2])
plt.plot(grid, c[3]);
```

So, this gets me
this, which looks like what I want, but it is super slow to run.

[image: plot of three PDFs]

I want to implement this equation to **sum two independent random variables** and get their discretized PDF.

[image: convolution integral]

Other questions suggested to use scipy.signal.fftconvolve

```
x = fftconvolve(pmfs, pmfs, 'same')
plt.plot(grid, x);
```

But it got me this. Why is it different?

[image: Plot of one PDF]

Comment: Your function `conv` looks like it's heading in the right direction, although doesn't `b` need to start from the end and work backwards? You should test `conv` on some small examples before trying something bigger. E.g. the convolution of [1, 1] with [1, 1] should be [1, 2, 1], conv([1, 1], [1, 2, 1]) should be [1, 3, 3, 1], etc; conv(a, b) should be conv(b, a), etc. I find it useful to work with Octave for stuff like this, it has a function, also named `conv`. The plots from fftconvolve look right to me -- the bump should get smoother and smoother the more times it's convolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, looking at your examples probably what I am looking is not 'convolution' after all. I edited the question a little to clarify my intentions. A bit confused here

Comment: Yes, for the sum of variables, you want the convolution. If you are working with continuous densities, you'll have to be careful about normalization. My advice is to try this first with Octave to get a feel for the problem, since its `conv` function does exactly the right thing, and then implement something in Python if that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have zeroes on the left side (and right side) when computing PDF grid, otherwise F-image won't be computed properly

After running the code below

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from scipy.stats import exponweib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shape, scale, delta = 1.3, 12.0, 1.0e-1
dist = exponweib(a=1, loc=0, c=shape, scale=scale)

grid = np.arange(-50, 100, delta)
ewei = dist.pdf(grid)*delta

plt.plot(grid, ewei)
plt.show()

# %%
t = signal.fftconvolve(ewei, ewei, 'same')
plt.plot(grid, t)
plt.show()
```

I got nice picture for convolved distribution

[image]